# wp_nav_menu_items - First position in the nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress, header, nav, wp-nav-menu-item

I am using the following code to add a search box into the navigation menu:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
   $items .= '<li class="menu-searchbox">' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
   return $items;
}
```

It works great, but it adds the search box at the end of the menu as the last `<li>` item

Is there any way the search box could be added as the first item on the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
    $searchbox = '<li class="menu-searchbox">' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';

    return $searchbox.$items;
}
```